# Draggable() is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am posting this question for a second time. and i still didn't get any answer. Its been like four days and i have been stuck into this problem. draggable() is not working in dynamically created tables i have compared the DOM of manually created table and dynamic table every thing is same, but it works in manually created table and not in dynamic table. It means in manually i can move the table columns like reordering and not in dynamic. Please i need help in this. below is my code.

```
function addTab() {
        var tab_title = $tab_title_input.val() || 'Tab '+tab_counter;
        //alert(tab_title);
        $tabs.tabs('add', '#tabs-'+tab_counter, tab_title);                 

        var newTableDiv = $("<div />",{id: 'dialog'+tab_counter});          
        newTableDiv.appendTo("body");           
        alert("div appended to body"+" "+'dialog'+tab_counter);
        var setCSS = {
            'width' : '100%',
            'cellspacing' : '1px',
            'cellpadding' : '2px'
        }

        var newTable = $('<table class="ui-widget" width="100%" border="0"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">'+
                    '<thead id="myTableHead'+tab_counter+'" class="ui-widget-header" style="display: table-header-group;">'+
                    '<tr><th><strong>Symbol</strong></th>'+
                    '<th><strong>Price</strong></th>'+
                    '<th><strong>Volume</strong></th>'+
                    '<th><strong>Buy</strong></th>'+
                    '<th><strong>Sell</strong></th></tr></thead>'+
                    '<tbody id="sortable'+tab_counter+'" class="ui-widget-content" style="display: table-row-group;">'+ 
'<tr><td>PSO</td><td>100.00</td><td>12</td><td>120.00</td><td>130.00</td></tr>'+
'<tr><td>ASO</td><td>200.00</td><td>11</td><td>120.00</td><td>130.00</td></tr></tbody></table>').attr('id', 'myTable'+tab_counter);
        $(newTableDiv).append(newTable);

        $('#myTable'+tab_counter).tablesorter(); 
        $('#myTable'+tab_counter).draggable(); //**not working**

        $( '#sortable'+tab_counter).sortable();         

        if ( $("#myTable"+tab_counter).length > 0 ) {
            alert("id exists");
        }
        alert("#myTable"+tab_counter);


        var myDiv = $("<div />", { "class":"ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom",id: 'tabs-'+tab_counter});
        myDiv.append("#tabs");

        $("#sortable"+tab_counter).show();
        $("#myTableHead"+tab_counter).show();

        $('#dialog'+tab_counter).prependTo('#tabs-'+tab_counter);           
        tab_counter++;
        //alert(tab_counter);
    }
```

I need help in this.

Comment: @Java_Newbie Does it break completely? What do you mean dynamically created table? Dynamically created by what? Is there any difference in markup between the tables (manual/dynamic)? Are there any environment differences between the two types (plugins or others)?

Comment: @JohnP.....it doen't break completely. dynamically means i create a table on fly, dynamic table. now there is another table which i am creating manually and when i use draggable() with it it works fine. but when i use with dynamic table it doesn't drag the table columns. I have also use a third party plugin http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/ it also works fine with manually created table but when it comes to dynamically created table it does'nt drag the table columns. I have also checked the markup using firbug both are same as well.

Comment: Your table is a widget, added to a new tab, and you want to drag around what exactly? The table headers and have the column move? It would be good if you could provide a screenshot of what this is exactly

Comment: @Gary Green....Yes exactly...the table headers and have the column move.

Comment: Just read your comment about dragtable, where is this called and initialised on the newly created table? I don't see it anywhere.... Your using `.draggable` but this is a jQuery UI function, and not your dragtable.

Comment: @Gary Green...i am not using now dragtable() because i thought that this is javascript library and might be this would be the reason it is not working on dynamic jquery table. that is why now i am using jqueryUI function which is .draggable().

Comment: @Gary Green...this javascript library dragtable() also works fine on manually created table by adding a class="draggable", but when i add this class in dynamically created table it fails to work.

Comment: @Java, jQuery UI draggable does not offer this functionality by doing simple `.draggable` -- you'll need to utilise a helper function, or stick with dragtable.

Comment: @Gary Green...i want to stick with with dragtable library. but when i add this as a class for e.g var dynamicTable = $('<table class="draggable">') it is not working. i will try your solution of using helper function.

Comment: @Gary Green... suppose if i want to use this javascript library in jquery,can you tell me how can i add class="draggable" during dynamic created table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using `.draggable` which is a jQuery UI method but it won't work to drag around the columns simply by attaching it to the table header. You'll need to ultilise a helper function:

For **dragtable**, although the documentation says to:

> Add class="draggable" to any table you might like to reorder.

This is a bit simplistic to say because the developer should realise things can be created dynamically in Javascript!

In other words, just simply adding the class `draggable` to the dynamically created table will NOT work. This is because draggable has already add event listeners after executing the `init` for all the tables when the DOM is ready. Changing the class will not automatically add an event listener. If this was a jQuery plugin, it could of used `.live` to attach event listeners to any dynamically created table now and in the future, but unfortunately it's not.

You'll need to attach a dragtable onto the newly created table, try:

```
dragtable.makeDraggable(newTable);
```

---

**Edit:**

Make sure your acting on the table element itself, not a jQuery object i.e.:

```
dragtable.makeDraggable(newTable[0]);
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/64pyb/

Comment: @Gary Geen....dragtable.makeDraggable(newTable); is not working, giving error. I am very new to jquery,now i am onto helper function. I will study helper function first and then will tell you the results.

Comment: See update, it's because your acting on the jQuery object, yet the dragtable is expecting just the table element. You can do `newTable.get(0)` to get the table element, or just get the element by doing `newTable[0]` -- I've provided a fiddle which demonstrates it working. You don't even need a classname.

Comment: Garyyyyy...Thankyouuuuuu sooooo much, it worked :). Its been like two to three days i have been involved in this problem. Thankyou so much.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it all sorted.